# inerting timestamp into table

Tags: java, sqlite, timestamp, prepared-statement

My database column datatype is timestamp.  How do I insert the current date and time using a PreparedStatement or Statement?

I have tried this:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
System.out.println("Current Date : " + dateFormat.format(date));

pstmt.setDate(9, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

But the value inserted in the table is 1328847536746. This not right, i am using sqlite

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Update this question if you have anything new to add.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate `Timestamp` value class in `java.sql`.

```
pstmt.setTimeStamp(9, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) explains:

> ```
> public class Timestamp
> extends Date
> ```
>
> A thin wrapper around `java.util.Date` that allows the JDBC API to identify this as an SQL TIMESTAMP value.

Comment: when i did like what u said , the value inserted into database is 1328847536746

Comment: @user1102019, that looks like the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 which is a common way of storing timestamps.  What about that is causing you problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use [setTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
pstmt.setTimestamp(9, Timestamp.valueOf("2002-03-13 11:10:15.01"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've used so far to get it done

```
Timestamp nextRunTimestamp = null;
if(endDate != null || !endDate.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dateFormat.parse(endDate);
    Calendar tempDate = dateFormat.getCalendar();
    tempDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, nextRunTime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    tempDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, nextRunTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    tempDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, nextRunTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    tempDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, nextRunTime.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    if(nextRunTime.before(tempDate) || nextRunTime.equals(tempDate))
    {
        nextRunTimestamp = new Timestamp(nextRunTime.getTimeInMillis());
    }
}
else
{
    nextRunTimestamp = new Timestamp(nextRunTime.getTimeInMillis());
}
statement.setTimestamp(2, nextRunTimestamp);
statement.setInt(3, result.getInt("id"));
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss); // any Date format
System.out.println("Current Date : " + df.format(new Date()));

pstmt.setDate(9, to_timestamp(df.format(new Date()),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Here you can use `TO_DATE('todayDate', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')`  or

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('todayDate', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```